# Telerik Open Access Profiler Does Not Catch Error Message, what should I do?

Tags: sql-server, orm, error-handling, profiler, openaccess

### On the data side:

I have a table.

This table has a number of fields.

And this table has been added an index that is unique. The intention of this index was to not allow the insertion of Duplicate values.

The table has been manually tested and it complies with that functionality.  That is, it works for the purpose intended. The table does not accept duplicate values, and every row entered is unique.

### On the Telerik Kendo side:

In my application, I have set up the ORM Open Access UI grid profiler. I know that the SQL statement throws an error when I insert duplicate values because I have tested it and read it.

However, when I insert the duplicate value via the application, with the ORM Open Access window enabled in order to visualize it, the profiler DOES NOT catch it.
There is no error message.

I have tried every piece of advice that I have read in this forum in order to make the Open Access catch the error, but nothing has worked.

**My question is: how can I make the ORM Open Access profiler catch the error that is being generated by the SQL statement every time I insert a duplicate value?**

I know this question will be useful to other users who may be facing the same struggles.

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge and providing your guidance.

Comment: Have you checked the Telerik forums?

Comment: Yes. I have. There isn't any post that could come even close to the issue that I am dealing with. There should be a way I could make the profiler catch the error. But this is so unusual that even my supervisor is surprised that Telerik is not catching it. Time to come here and escalate the error. I hope someone can guide me, or at  least point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Telerik OpenAccess ORM and I never had this issue. I just tested it again with the last version of OpenAccess ORM and OpenAccess Profiler, and the exception was caught and shown. In the options of the Profiler, there is an Alert rule for Runtime Exception, lest you uncheck this rule? If the rule is not checked the runtime exceptions will not be shown.
If this is not the case, I would recommend you to write about your issue in Telerik Forums or to contact their Support team. There you will receive more help.